# Magento2 nightly build install script

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I was wondering if there is way to install/upgrade Magento2 every night using a shell install script run by cron. Our server runs Centos/Nginx/Php-fpm.

**Question:** I was fiddling with some code and thought I'd share it now - because maybe an auto-cron isntall script for Magento2 already exists?

```
#!/bin/sh

su myusername
MAGEDIR="/home/myusername/domains/example.com/public_html/"  
cd $MAGEDIR
rm -rf $MAGEDIR*
git clone https://github.com/magento/magento2.git
chown -R myusername $MAGEDIR
sudo find $MAGEDIR -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
sudo find $MAGEDIR -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
composer install
chown -R myusername $MAGEDIR

check for complete reinstall flag or nightly update

cd $MAGEDIR/bin
if {update}
php magento setup:install --base_url=http://example.com --backend_frontname=beheer --db_host --db_name --db_user --db_password --admin_firstname=admin --admin_lastname=admin --admin_email=info@admin.com --admin_user=admin --admin_password=MYPASSWD --language=en_US --currency=dollar --timezone=Ams/nl
{else}
complete reinstall here
--clean_database

check for sample data flag
```

Comment: why would you want to uninstall/install it every night?

Comment: We report/share code/try to improve Magento. And for this often the Mage2 team asks if we are running last version. Also - for testing purposes I would really not like to spend a lot if time on installation. Rather I would like to call a script. Get the last version. Test whatever I want to verify. Doesn't seem so strange if you ask me. I have seen many systems that have nightly updates. Have you seen/made such a script?

Comment: Also - to date we have not found a public demo (last version) - so we need to install it on our own server. Or are Mage2 public demo's available? Not being alpha etc

Answer (score 1):

This tweet by Mark Shust might help - Docker installations of Magento 2. (But note that at GA, the recommended way to develop will be via Composer builds, not git clone, so the code will only update when a patch etc is released.) https://twitter.com/markshust/status/608818961275211777